# Material UI @mui/material/Button vs @material-ui/core/Button, when did it change, where are docs for older version

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to add Material UI to a React project I'm working on.  A quick searched turned up the article [Medium.com article Getting Started With Material-UI For React](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/getting-started-with-material-ui-for-react-material-design-for-react-364b2688b555).
I started watching the video which said to use:

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

And in the code to use:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'    // Syntax #1
```

But I ran into problems, so looked at the offical [MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/#default-installation) which say:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

And using

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';  // Sytnax #2
```

**Are both versions from the same Material UI team?  If so, how do I get the older docs?  Or would it be better to use the latest version (Syntax #2) of Material UI 5.13.x and just use the https://mui.com website?**

#### Searching for solution

- Going to old website https://material-ui.com simply redirects to new site https://mui.com/core/.

I found both both syntaxs being used:

- Button API - https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/  - Uses syntax #2
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/material-ui-button-api/# - Uses syntax #1
- [Why You Should Upgrade To Material-UI V5](https://marmelab.com/blog/2022/02/27/mui-v5-rocks.html#:%7E:text=Material%2Dui%20V5%20introduces%20some,as%20the%20internal%20styling%20engine.) from https://marmelab.com/blog/...
- https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/overview/#material-ui-vs-base-ui which did not answer my question. - Uses Syntax #2 so perhaps v5 introduced the new namespace and syntax.

Comment: `@material-ui` is versions 1-4, `@mui` is version 5. You should use the most recent version, it will save you headaches later on. But your article may not be as helpful since they've changed the styling libraries underneath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `material-ui` introduced the 5th version, the team renamed `material-ui` to `mui`, list of renamed packages:

```
@material-ui/core -> @mui/material
@material-ui/system -> @mui/system
@material-ui/unstyled -> @mui/core
@material-ui/styles -> @mui/styles
@material-ui/icons -> @mui/icons-material
@material-ui/lab -> @mui/lab
@material-ui/types -> @mui/types
@material-ui/styled-engine -> @mui/styled-engine
@material-ui/styled-engine-sc ->@mui/styled-engine-sc
@material-ui/private-theming -> @mui/private-theming
@material-ui/codemod -> @mui/codemod
@material-ui/docs -> @mui/docs
@material-ui/envinfo -> @mui/envinfo
```

Docs for [v5](https://mui.com/), [v4](https://v4.mui.com/), [v3](https://v3.mui.com/)

Comment: Where did you find the list of renamed packages?

Comment: @PatS https://v5-0-6.mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#update-mui-version